# Transposition errors divisibility?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was reading about dyslexia (which I believe I have though I have never been diagnosed) when I came upon this [strange statement](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/transposition-error.asp):

> When two adjacent numbers are transposed, the resulting mathematical error will always be divisible by 9 (e.g., (72-27)/9 = 5).

I tried transposing a number of numbers and they were, indeed, divisible by 9.

I'm terrible at math; it was always my worst subject (and consequently? my most disliked) though I had to use it multiple times every day in my work.

Could someone explain (as if to an idiot) why the above holds true?

(I did read that this site was all-purpose, including for beginners. Please forgive me if this is OT.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write the first number as $10 a + b$, and the second as $10 b + a$ (in your example, $a = 7$ and $b = 2$). Then

$$(10a + b) - (10 b + a) = 9a - 9b = 9(a - b)$$

is divisible by $9$.

Comment: +1 for an answer in terms the OP asked for. You might note (and even prove) that the difference will be divisible by $9$ even if the transposed digits aren't adjacent.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the answer and admire your ability to reduce it to this level. Would you believe that I can deliver babies, repair complicated lacerations, treat hypertensive encephalopathy, learned to read hieroglyphics passably well (which is a complicated depiction of a dead language), and have mastered other intellectually challenging material, but can't quite understand why (10a + b) - (10b + a) = 9a - 9b? I keep staring at it/trying to make sense of it, and I think I'm catching on, but I'm not sure. Our definitions of "idiot" differ by several orders of magnitude, I suspect. ;)

Comment: @anongoodnurse this is what schools would have called "grouping 'like' terms". First, removing the parentheses requires that the subtraction be distributed to the two terms to the right of it: $(10a+b) - (10b+a) = 10a + b - 10b - a$. Then grouping 'like' terms, $10a-a$ is $9a$  and $b-10b$ is $-9b$. Together they make $9a-9b = 9(a-b)$ which is 9 times a whole number.

Comment: @JimN - Oh, I like that explanation. Thank you!